# F# not able to solve function in async

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm really F# noob and I tried to code very simple program which iterate list in parallel. Here is simplified code

```
let test = ["xx"; "yy"; "zz"]
let urls = 
    ["http://google.com";"http://google.com"]

let p l = async {
    let t = test
    for k in t do
        printf "%s" k
} 

let find = 
    urls
    |> List.map p
    |> Async.Parallel 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
   find  
   printfn "%A" argv
   0 // return an integer exit code
```

Unfortunately this program never finish. It can't solve this line:

```
    let t = test
```

It never get over that line. But if I change find and main function in this way:

```
let find = 
    urls
    |> List.map p
    |> Async.Parallel 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
   find 
   |> Async.RunSynchronously
   |> ignore
   printfn "%A" argv
   0 // return an integer exit code
```

Everything works fine as expected. Can somebody explain me the difference please?

Also if I do not call test function but rather code list into "p" function

```
let t = ["xx"; "yy"; "zz"]
```

It works fine in first version.

Comment: what do you mean with "can't solve `let t = test`"?

Comment: do make both versions behave more similar you should make `find` into a   function - the difference in the second one is that the `async` computation starts as soon as you do `Async.RunSynchronoulsy` - but this code is quite confusing as I don't have a clue what you want to do (I guess you copy&pasted the default async samples and removed all the url-fetching stuff?)

Comment: Yes you are right Castern I have removed all url-fetching code. John's aswer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is that `find` is not a function, but a value.  As a result `find` actually runs before `main` (in the first example).

Changing the definition to `let find()` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: yes - this or move the `RunSynchronously` into `main` - seems that starting a `Async`-workflow outside/before the entry-point will indeed put the programm into *bottom* ;) (never noticed before - should be interesting to find out why - thanks for this question btw - +1)